# Show Java program output on cmd after compiled by Sublime text 3

Tags: java, c++, python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublime-build

I'm using Sublime Text 3 for writing and compiling my java programs but the output on Sublime console isn't helpful because we can't give inputs. I had found the sublime build code for C and C++ to show the output on cmd but haven't succeeded in Java. This is what I've written in my java.sublime-build file.

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac", "$file_name"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",

    "variants": [

        {
            "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "java", "$file_base_name"],
            "shell": true,
            "name": "Run"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to run the cmd opens but it isn't able to compile the java file and says, "Could not find or locate the main class". I want to run the program that I've just compiled in a cmd window (not in the Sublime console) What should I add to that command? Thank you.

Comment: are you sure, that the `$file_name` includes the `.java` extension and the `$file_base_name` doesn't?

Comment: @HarshvardhanJoshi Yes, I'm sure.

Comment: great, then try using instead of just `cmd` use `shell_cmd`... this might work for you.

Comment: you can also combine the compile and run command into one as following `javac $file_name && java $file_base_name`

Comment: @HarshvardhanJoshi Using **shell_cmd** isn't working :(

Comment: Your variant for running the program doesn't compile the code first, so it will only work if you use the main build to do that first. You probably also need to add a working_dir key to the build as well.

Comment: @OdatNurd Can you please correct my code and show me how?

Comment: @GAjeet Looks like you got yourself sorted out! :)

Comment: Yeah, It also doesn't need any additional packages to do so... :)

Answer (score 0):

I myself figured out my query and I am able to run my Java, C/C++, and Python programs and they are all showing the output in a pop-up command prompt and we can even run interactive programs in which programs take inputs.

I wanna share all those sublime-build codes with you all.

JAVA SUBLIME BUILD CODE

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac", "$file_name", "&&", "start","cmd", "/k", "java", "$file_base_name"],
    "shell": true,
    "quiet": true
}
```

C SUBLIME BUILD CODE

```
{
    "cmd": ["gcc.exe", "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file_name", "&&", "start", "cmd", "/k", "$file_base_name"],
    "shell": true,
    "quiet": true
}
```

C++ SUBLIME BUILD CODE

```
{
    "cmd": ["c++.exe", "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file_name", "&&", "start", "cmd", "/k", "$file_base_name"],
    "shell": true,
    "quiet": true
}
```

PYTHON SUBLIME BUILD CODE

```
{
    "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "python", "$file_name"],
    "shell": true,
    "quiet": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is perfect but if you just want to see the output in the sublime text console without any cmd pop-up, then you can use:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "javac $file && java $file_base_name"
}
```

However, this is only for viewing output. It is not capable of accepting user inputs.

For those who don't know where to place this code, follow the steps:

```
Tools > Build System > New Build System ...
```

Then, paste whichever code snippet meets your requirements. Save the file as `<filename>.sublime-build`. Let's say runJava.sublime-build.

Then,

```
Tools > Build System > runJava.sublime-build
```

Then use `Ctrl + B` to compile and run the selected .java file.

You can also visit [here](https://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-compile-and-run-a-java-program-with-sublime-text-3), if you want the same process written in this answer along with screenshots.